# Yammer - sending Notification through Rest API

Tags: yammer

New to Yammer Integration - had a question - hopefully someone has faced this before.

Integrating Yammer with our ASP.Net application using Rest API - If i post a message a message created by a user in our Application to Yammer, Is there any way to notify certain key people in the users group about this new posting (Something like the Add people to notify in the Yammer web site)?

Thanks in Advance

Regards
Sid

Answer (score 3):

When you post a new message it bubbles up to the top of the group and is visible for other users. Most of the time this is fine and group members will notice it. You can also @mention (pronounced "at-mention" users in the message body. This will result in the message appearing in their Yammer inbox, and they may also get other notifications.

To @mention a user you need to know their permalink. You can get their permalink from the users end point. The permalink is in the name element available from end points like https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/current.json. Once you have a the permalink you just insert it in the message with an @ symbol before it. Yammer will then turn this into a link, and take other action because the user is explicitly mentioned.

Comment: could you please help me with some example.