# Posting a message from a Yammer app - notifications?

Tags: yammer

We are posting a message to Yammer from our app about a specific user> Is it possible for the user to receive a notification about this message and if so how do we enforce this?

I've tried including "@username" in the message body but to no avail...

Answer (score 1):

When a user is @mentioned ("at mentioned") in a conversation that thread should appear in the user's inbox. It won't appear in the notifications because that is reserved for specific notifications.

When you @mention the user today is the @username part being correctly linked to their profile? If not you might want to check out my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678043/yammer-sending-notification-through-rest-api) on this subject. Once the permalink is used you should see it replaced with the user's profile name, and this is what triggers the connection. It should then appear in the inbox of the @mentioned user, even if they don't follow the conversation in their inbox.